# Swift - Parse query by two conditions Not Creating Proper Result

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have a class with three objects:

```
Class: Follow
Follow["follower"] = Current User
Follow["following"] = IndexPath of row for button click
Follow["status"] = Pending or Approved
```

I now have functionality in place with my tableview controller where the tableview is populated with all users excluding the current user. The users profile image and username are displayed, as well as an "Add User" button. When the add user button is clicked, the "Follow" class objects are set as show above with the status set to "Pending". This functionality works, but what I am trying to do is update the "Add User" text to "Pending" when the button is clicked for each individual users row. I am currently apply two conditions to my Parse query, "status" = "Pending" and "follower" equal to "current user's username" This technique doesn't appear to work as the text does not change when a button is clicked. Any help?

Query:

```
//** Query Pending Frienship Statuses and Change Button Title **//

        var friendshipStatusQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")

        friendshipStatusQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: "Pending")
        friendshipStatusQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)


        friendshipStatusQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                for object in objects {
                cell.addUserButton.setTitle("Pending", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }
            } else {
               println(error)
            }
        }
```

Full Code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        loadParseData()




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return userArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        var individualUser = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = individualUser.username as String

        var profileImage = individualUser["profileImage"] as? PFFile

        if profileImage != nil {

        profileImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (result, error) in

            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: result)

        })
        } else {
            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "profileImagePlaceHolder")

        }

        cell.usernameLabel.text = username

        cell.addUserButton.tag = row

        cell.addUserButton.addTarget(self, action: "addUser:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        //** Query Pending Frienship Statuses and Change Button Title **//

        var friendshipStatusQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")

        friendshipStatusQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: "Pending")
        friendshipStatusQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)


        friendshipStatusQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                for object in objects {
                cell.addUserButton.setTitle("Pending", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }
            } else {
               println(error)
            }
        }


        return cell

    }

    func loadParseData() {

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: user.username)


        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                    for object in objects {


                        self.userArray.addObject(object)



                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }






    @IBAction func addUser(sender: UIButton) {

        println("Button Triggered")

        let addUserButton : UIButton = sender as UIButton!

        let user : PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(addUserButton.tag) as! PFObject



        var follow = PFObject(className: "Follow")



        follow["following"] = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(sender.tag)
        follow["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
        follow["status"] = "Pending"


        follow.saveInBackground()


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a button is clicked, your addUser: method gets called which in the method does not change the title to pending at all. Just looks like it adds a new object to the Follow Class.

I'm also a little confused at your Parse Query in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

You query for your pending friendships and for every one you find, you change the cell you're currently creating status to pending numerous times. I think you should alter the query to just evaluate if the friendship is pending with the current cells username. You should be able to create a faster query and maybe only use countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock since you do not seem to do anything with the objects you return from the query.

Let me know if I can help anymore or provide clarification. I hope I understood the question correctly

Comment: hey @Josh Harnet, thanks for the answer. I actually forgot to update that since I was focused on getting the query correct. the addUser: method is now changing to "Pending" with `addUserButton.setTitle("Pending", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`. 

In regard to the query: I started off with only using the condition where "status" = "Pending", but the issue with that condition is that since one cell matched that condition all buttons were updated. I thought this new route of using "follower" would fix that, but it didn't. Can you take me through your thoughts for the query?

Comment: Correct Me If I'm Mistaken: Your goal is to populate a table view full of users (besides yourself) and when you select a button on a cell corresponding to a user, changing the title of the button to "Pending"

Comment: Yes, Change the title in addition to setting objects for the "Follow" class like it is laid out in the current code.

Comment: what's the initial title for a button in your custom cell? You could setTitle for UIControlState.Selected to be "Pending" when you create the button. In a normal state it will have "Follow" or whatever you choose. Than when selected, the title will change and your selector will be called

Comment: The initial title is just "Button". I'm not sure if the button state would be the best approach to solving this. I feel like there could be scenarios were you there could be a tableview reload and the buttons could be thought of as unselected. I think matching the button text to the state of the Parse query is an error proof approach. Please let me know if you think that I shouldn't worry about the scenario I mentioned.